# Yii : how to count records in a model?

Tags: php, yii

I have following code to fetch data from a model.

```
$notifyModel = Notification::model()->findByAttributes(array(
                  'user_id'=> Yii::app()->user->uid
               ));
```

Now I want to count the number of rows fetched. 
Neither `$notifyModel->count()` work nor `count($notifyModel)`.
It is very simple but googling did not help.

Comment: Just as an aside note, findByAttributes() will return a count of one, always. findAllByAttributes() will return > 1/.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
$notifyModels = Notification::model()->findAllByAttributes(array(
            'user_id'=> Yii::app()->user->uid
        ));

$count = count($notifyModels);
```

Or

```
$count = Notification::model()->countByAttributes(array(
            'user_id'=> Yii::app()->user->uid
        ));
```

Comment: When I put 'findAllByAttributest ' got this error: 'Trying to get property of non-object '

Comment: Add a line with `Yii::app()->user->uid;` by itself and see if that gives the error or not. By default `uid` is not defined as a property of the user component, so unless you extended it properly it would give an error.

Comment: uid is working with other things. I have explicitly defined it in UserIdentity class

Comment: with 'findByAttributes' it returns wrong data and with your solution it generates error!

Comment: ->user->uid, what is the user and uid in that?

Comment: I have table companies, I want to print a number of records in that table on my frontend/site/home.php, how can I do this?

Comment: @ShaileshYadav Please create a new question, rather than making a comment on a 5 year old question.

Comment: First example is extremely inefficient, you should avoid using it.

Comment: @rob006 is correct. First fetching all the data into php memory and then using count() on the array is pretty much retarded. I am in a 10y old code now fixing this exact inefficiency because a page is not loading when the table got a little bigger...

Answer (score 31):

the right usage of count():

```
    $userid =  Yii::app()->user->uid;
    $count = Notification::model()->count( 'user_id=:userid', array(':userid' => $userid));
```

Please see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#count-detail

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
$userid =  Yii::app()->user->uid;

$notifyModel = Notification::model()->count(
           array('condition' => 'user_id=:userid', 
                 'params'=>array(':userid' => $userid)
                ));
```

Comment: I am new in Yii framework, I have table companies, I want to print a number of records in that table on my frontend/site/home.php, how can I do this? (DB name-yii2advanced)

Answer (score 3):

```php
$count = Notification::model()->countByAttributes(array(
    'user_id'=> Yii::app()->user->uid
));
```

Comment: there is no things to describe all the work to count is done by the yii function countByattributes other things there are all normal

Answer (score 2):

Since the questions `title` is about calling the count function `in a model` I'll add some for those beginners reading this :)

A function inside a model could look like this:

```
/**
 * Count the number of rows which match the user ID
 * @param int $uid The user ID
 * @return int The number of found rows
 */
public function getCountByUserID($uid)
{
    $count = $this->count(array(
        'condition'=>'user_id = :uid',
        'params'=>array(
            ':uid'=>$uid,
        ),
    ));
    return $count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

simple ways:

```
$model = News::model()->findAll(); //returns AR objects
         $count = count($model);
```

Comment: You shouldn't do this as it loads all models into memory. Use count method as above

Answer (score 2):

I think it is much faster than others

```
$userTable=User::model()->tableName();
$userid =  Yii::app()->user->uid;
$criteria=new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->select=count(id);
$criteria->compare('user_id',$userid);
$count=Yii::app()->db->commandBuilder->createFindCommand($userTable,$criteria)->queryScalar();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the most simple way to do that:

```
$count = Table::Model()
         ->count("field=:field", array("field" => $fildID));
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 1):

That method is wrong!
You trying to get by selecting all rows from database, you load the server, but that's wrong way!
All you need to do :

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {{...table_name...}}";

$count = intval(Yii::app()->db
  ->createCommand($sql)
  ->queryScalar());
```

Or you can create function in your model:

```
Class User extends CActiveRecord
{
    private $_total;

    public function getTotalItems()
    {
        if( empty( $this->_total )) {
            $this->_total = intval(Yii::app()->db
                ->createCommand($sql)->queryScalar());
        }
        return $this->_total;
    }

}
```

then you can use this functions like this:

```
$totalItems = User::model()->totalItems;
```

or :

```
$model = User::model()->findByPk( $uid );
$totalItems = $model->totalItems;
```

or :

```
$model = new User;
$totalItems = $model->totalItems;
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to find count with SQL query else it will degrade your system performance. 
There are three way to find out count with the SQL query itself in `Yii 1` `CActiveRecord`, those are:

**1. count() method**

Finds the number of rows satisfying the specified query condition.

*Example :*

```
$count = Notification::model()->count('user_id'=> Yii::app()->user->uid);
```

**2. countByAttributes() method (available since v1.1.4)**

Finds the number of rows that have the specified attribute values.

*Example :*

```
$count = Notification::model()->countByAttributes(array(
    'user_id'=> Yii::app()->user->uid
));
```

**3. countBySql() method**

Finds the number of rows using the given SQL statement. This is equivalent to calling `CDbCommand::queryScalar` with the specified SQL statement and the parameters.

*Example:*

```
$count = Notification::model()
         ->countBySql("select *from notification where user_id=:userId",
            array(':userId'=>Yii::app()->user->uid)
           );
```

> Don't use the following code, which will reduce system performance:
>
> ```
> $notifyModels = Notification::model()->findAllByAttributes(array(
>             'user_id'=> Yii::app()->user->uid
>         ));
> $count = count($notifyModels);
> ```
>
> Because, there are two function call to find the count

Answer (score -1):

In my research, The easiest and Best Practice is like below.

```
$notifyModel = Notification::model()->count(array('user_id'=> Yii::app()->user->uid));
```